# Is stdin/ stdout/ stderr or cin/ cout/ cerr process safe?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I'm not talking about thread safe, by process safe I mean, for every process by default OS opens three file descriptors when it starts a new process i.e. stdin, stdout and stderr, but as we know everything in UNIX is file, so I am assuming that these are the actual *physical files* which is shared with different processes.

My questions (which are based on the assumption that these are different files which are shared with all the processes, and of course if we have file descriptors then we have files) are:

1. Why there is no interlacing between the output to cout/ cerr or stdout/stderr when multiple process use it at the same time?
2. How different processes share only that part of the cout/ cerr or stdout/ stderr which is written by them?

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect

Comment: @RichardCritten could you please elaborate why? as when we have file descriptor then we should have files as well by definition of file descriptor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Comment: As the link says they are per-process __streams__ not physical files.  A file handle is an abstract concept and does not need to refer to an actual file.

Answer (score 13):

> …as we know everything in UNIX is file…

This is an overgeneralization.

> I am assuming that cout and cerr are the physical files which is shared with different processes.

Your assumption is incorrect. They are not "physical" files; they do not have filenames, and are not stored on disk.

`cout` and `cerr` (more commonly known as stdout and stderr) are file descriptors. They can refer to files, but more commonly refer to a terminal, or to pipes. Each process has its own set of file descriptors; stdin/stdout/stderr are simply the names that each process uses for a standard set of three file descriptors used for input and output.

> Why there is no interlacing between the output to cout/ cerr when multiple process use it at the same time?

Another incorrect assumption. Multiple processes writing to the *same* file descriptor can result in interleaved output. However, multiple processes writing to *different* file descriptors do not interfere with one another.

Comment: how multiple process with same file descriptor for stdin/stdout/stderr i.e. 0,1 and 2 distinguish between there own stdin/stdout and stderr?

Comment: file descriptors are specific for a process, they are not shared across processes, unless there is parent child relationship

Comment: @Vishrant File descriptors aren't global they are unique to each process

Answer (score 2):

To answer your main question a short answer will be **NO**.

Consider the following flow:

```
A is running
A is running
A is running
A is running
A forks a new process B
```

All entries in the `PDT` of process B will point to the same descriptors process A is pointing to, that includes `stderr`, `stdout` and `stdin`.

If in process A you print 1000 times `+` and in process B you print 1000 times `-`. 
Then you can expect your output to be mixed like this: 

 `++++++++---------+++++----------+++++------`

And that is because they share the same `stdout`.